# How can I put Objects with state under Version Control? Does it even make sense?

Tags: java, database, version-control

Suppose I have a User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

      @Id
      private int id;

      private String name;

      //Other fields and methods

}
```

At one point of time, the name is say 'XYZ' and at other point of time its 'ABC'. I want to keep track of both the states just as we  track files under version control system. These objects are stored in relational database. A crude approach which I could think of is to put the data of database itself under version control, but that's just not feasible as database table will have data for many such users and change in even any one of them will call for committing an update.

How can I achieve this? How do applications usually store edit history when they have to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using hibernate you could use [envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a JPA level interface for this?